# How to set the UILevel to INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC when performing a major upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building an installation/upgrade package with WiX.
I'm using the **WixUI_InstallDir** dialog set.

What I want to do is to have a fully automated installation (no wizard) when performing a major upgrade of the installed product.

Is it possible to:

- conditionally change the value of UILevel during the installation? (INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL / INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC)
- conditionally change the dialog set? (WixUI_InstallDir / WixUI_Minimal)

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BasicUI the UI Sequence isn't run.  The problem is you don't know if you are a MajorUpgrade until FindRelatedProducts runs and finds a related ProductCode.  I think the best you could do is put a condition on your WelcomeDlg to not be displayed when it's a Major Upgrade.

Comment: Agreed. The only way you could find this out first would be in a bootstrapper that performed the same checks as FindRelatedProducts, and launched the .msi accordingly.